# Uploading the KFP compiled pipeline (in json format) to the artifact registry (with Kubeflow pipeline format)

Tags: curl, kubeflow-pipelines, google-artifact-registry, vertex-ai-pipeline, kfp

I'm trying to upload the kubeflow pipeline to the artifact registry (with Kubeflow format). I'm using kfp.v2 for my project. The output of the pipeline is in json format after the compilation. To upload the file, I'm using "curl" command.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-F tags=v1,latest \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-F content=@output_pipelines/data_injection_pipeline.json \
https://us-central1-kfp.pkg.dev/project_1/kubeflow_testing
```

When I tried to run above script from terminal, I'm getting an error : "Request has an invalid argument: invalid extension type data_injection_pipeline.json."

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-F tags=v1,latest \
-F content=@output_pipelines/data_injection_pipeline.json \
https://us-central1-kfp.pkg.dev/project_1/kubeflow_testing
```

And, when I tried to run above script from terminal, I'm getting an error : "Request has an invalid argument: missing boundary in request or not a multipart request".

I'm eager to find out the solution. Additionally, please provide guidance if I have made any errors, as I am not well-versed in "curl" commands.

Comment: As per the error message `Request has an invalid argument: invalid extension type data\_injection\_pipeline.json` It seems like you are using the file extension of your pipeline in JSON format which is not supported. As stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/create-pipeline-template#use-the-template-in-kfp-client:~:text=The%20payload%20of%20the%20request%20is%20the%20contents%20of%20the%20pipeline_spec.yaml%20file%20\(or%20.zip%20package\)) change the format of your file to `.yaml file (or .zip package)`.

Comment: Also can you try replacing `content` with `file` and also `Content-Type` should be multipart or related for multupart request.

Comment: Do not set content-type unless you have a reason. The content type should be `multipart/form-data`. Only YAML and ZIP formats are supported.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni JohnHanley, Thanks for your responses, but since I'm using kfp.v2, the compiled pipeline is in json format. I tried to create the file in yaml, but I'm getting an issue "the file extension need to be in .json format). Is there any other way, I can generate the file in yaml format instead of json format. I tried this method too [link](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/migration/#pipeline-package-file-extension), but failed to create the file in yaml format. 
Thanks for your help.